# How to make a document with code in it?

Tags: text, markup, code-snippets

I'm trying to make a document that has both instructions in normal text and code snippets intertwined together.

I would like it to look like a javadoc or a wiki page type format.

Is there a language like LaTeX or a editor that does this?

Thanks

*If anyone can reword this question to make it more relevant please do

Answer (score 0):

`org-mode` in emacs has this. More at http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/intro.html

```
* Heading
  Some Text
  #+begin_src ruby
  require 'date'
  "This file was last evaluated on #{Date.today}"
  #+end_src
```

Answer (score 0):

Are yoou looking for a markdown editor?
Read the wikipedia entry about [markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) and then try the tutorial  shown on this page

http://oscargodson.github.com/EpicEditor/

to embed a free markdown editor in your webpage (assuming you are building a web based system).

From the wikipedia page:

Code

To include code (formatted in monospace font), you can either surround inline code with backticks (`), like in

Some text with `some code` inside,

or indent several lines of code by at least four spaces, as in:

```
line 1 of code
line 2 of code
line 3 of code
```

The latter option makes Markdown retain all whitespace—as opposed to the usual behaviour, which, by removing line breaks and excess spaces, would break indentation and code layout.